# Lxml not finding all tables on page?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to get some data and when I'm using lxml it's find 2 tables and not the 3rd which I want.  I suspect this has to do with the xpath or the way that specific table is being generated.

I'm trying to get the price history from: http://web.tmxmoney.com/pricehistory.php?qm_symbol=WDO.DB.A

Here are the different attempts I've made and the results.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def financialPriceData():
        priceData = requests.get('http://web.tmxmoney.com/pricehistory.php?qm_symbol=WDO.DB.A')
        PriceScraperTree = html.fromstring(priceData.content)
        #PriceTreeTickers = PriceScraperTree.xpath('//*[@id="innerContent"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()') # no luck. From Chrome.
        # PriceTreeTickers = PriceScraperTree.xpath('//table[@id="qm_history_historyContent"]') # no luck, can't find the table
        PriceTreeTickers = PriceScraperTree.xpath('//table')  # no luck, finds only 2 tables top of the page and bottom of the page data. When I look at text result the daily price is missing.
        print(PriceTreeTickers)

financialPriceData()
```

Comment: You cannot parse what is not there, the table data is generated using javascript/ajax calls, look at the actual source code returned and you won't see it anywhere

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, I saw that now but I thought if it renders on the page, wouldn't lxml/requests be able to get to it once I have the page loaded?  Sorry if it doesn't make sense I'm very new to web scraping

Comment: No worries, requests does not do dynamically loaded content, if you right click and choose view source in your browser, that is what requests will receive. I am having a look to see if I can get the data in json format

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you so much, but more than the specific answer if you could show me how you found it then that would help me much more.  I found the json request.  It's this /json/getPriceHistory.json.php but not sure how to call it.

Comment: really chrome dev tools or firebug are essential tools, in particular the network tab when it comes to scraping.